# FirebaseRecyclerViewAdapter display child's from multiple refs

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

I know that this questions has already been asked but I am looking for days and I haven't find the solution. Is there any way to display child's from multiple refs in one `FirebaseRecyclerViewAdapter`.I use GeoFire to find nearest places and store them in a list. The list have some uids. My database look like this.

```
 "Places" : {
        "yt1FNJ7CwYNnUTAjxuewwIb3eY22" : {  //uid
          "category1" : {
                 "-KXVfuOf2ZIk2ksFk7Sk" : {
                    "date" : "2016/11/28",
                    "name"  : "item1"
                  },
                  "-KXVfjzC_-_kTZqH8B1k" : {
                    "date" : "2016/11/27",
                     "name" : "item2"
                  }
                }
              }
    "Ks1FNJ7CwYNnUTAjxuewwIb3eY23" : {            //uid
          "category1" : {
                 "-KXVfuOf2ZIk2ksFk7Sk" : {
                    "date" : "2016/11/28",
                    "name"  : "item3"
                  },
                "-KXVfjzC_-_kTZqH8B1k" : {
                    "date" : "2016/11/27",
                     "name" : "item4"
                  }
                }
              }
      }
```

So how I display the items in the `RecyclerViewer` from all the GeoFire results?

Comment: You'll have to perform separate queries to get data for those refs.  It's mostly for that reason that I find 'FirebaeRecyclerViewAdapter' too inflexible

Comment: Yes, i agree ! FirebaeRecyclerViewAdapter has limited use capabilities  for now, but i believe that it will be upgraded soon .